# Trying to read a csv file in Jmeter using Beanshell Sampler

Tags: jmeter, xls

I am trying to read the cells in an xls file.This is the code I have.Please let me know where I am going wrong.I don't see any error in the logviewer but it isn't printing anything.

```
    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
    import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    public class ApacheCommonsCSV {

           public void readCSV() throws IOException {

                   String CSV_File_Path = "C:\\source\\Test.csv";
               // read the file
               Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_File_Path));
               // parse the file into csv values
               CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);

        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            // Accessing Values by Column Index
                       String name = csvRecord.get(0);
                       String product = csvRecord.get(1);
                       // print the value to console
                       log.info("Record No - " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber());
                       log.info("---------------");
                       log.info("Name : " + name);
                       log.info("Product : " + product);
                       log.info("---------------");
        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're **declaring** `readCSV()` function but **not calling it anywhere**, that's why your code doesn't even get executed.

You need to add this `readCSV()` function call and if you're lucky enough it will start working and if not - your will see an error in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

For example like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class ApacheCommonsCSV {

    public void readCSV() throws IOException {

        String CSV_File_Path = "C:\\source\\Test.csv";
        // read the file
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_File_Path));
        // parse the file into csv values
        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);

        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            // Accessing Values by Column Index
            String name = csvRecord.get(0);
            String product = csvRecord.get(1);
            // print the value to console
            log.info("Record No - " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber());
            log.info("---------------");
            log.info("Name : " + name);
            log.info("Product : " + product);
            log.info("---------------");
        }
    }

    readCSV(); // here is the entry point
}
```

Just make sure to have [commons-csv.jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Last 2 cents:

1. Any reason for not using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)?
2. Since [JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy right away. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) for reasons, tips and tricks.